# Simple Issue that I am Unable to Debug in IE9 (CSS I think)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, pseudo-class

I've got some issues with this heap of a junk browser IE and it is preventing me from using any addons to debug the issue(s).

If someone could be kind enough to take a look and let me know the problem please that would be ace.

Please see this site (it's only testing domain so I know there are tons of other problems on it) - 009rep.clubnetdev.com.

Hover over the 'Sale' item in the top navigation menu (whilst in IE9) and within the 2nd column, there appears to be a vertical line (border) randomly floating there (see screenshot below). I'm initially thinking it has something to do with the CSS psuedo classes first-child and last-child defined within this dropdown but if anyone can have a look and confirm what the problem is, I would really appreciate it - thanks.

[screenshot http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/7606/pick.png](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/7606/pick.png)

Displays fine in all other non IE browsers (as expected).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: Do you have Developer Tools enabled in IE? It comes with them, you just need to turn them on. It will give you a quasi-firebug-ish set of tools, one of which is a CSS inspector. You can click on an element, then see all the rules that apply to it. You can then turn the rules off one by one until you track down your issue.

Comment: Also you have a markup error `<tr>` element is closed twice: `</tr></tr>`

Comment: @chipcullen Yes have all the developer toolset enabled in IE but the browser completely screwed up on me and half of it including add ons weren't working for me making it awkward to debug. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @WojtekT Really? Hmm, can't see that. The product grid is called in using Magento's core calls so would be odd if this contained a markup error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

menurep.css, line 176

`.col_1 {width:145px; border-right: 1px solid #888;}`

The width 145px is causing this, as in the other dropdowns you use it for the text links on the left.

I would give this instance a different class so it doesn't get the right border applied to it at all.

One way you could do this is to target this specific column via its parent:

`.dropdown_1column .col_1 { border:0 }`

I also notice that all your `.col_*` classes have `display:inline` and `float:left;` applied which are conflicting statements as floating makes an element block anyway.

If you can't change any of the above easily, you may want to try z-index on this specific instance but I think this may cause other issues.

Comment: That's great, thanks Moin. Switched the class and problem solved. :) Yeah 3rd party extension and some of the code is a bit of a mess with it unfortunately. Thanks for pointing out the confliction though, I removed display:inline from the .col_* classes.